# Getting the Suggestions from the Current Location when working with Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm working with **Google Places API**  which gives the auto suggestions from the keyword mentioned in **AutoCompleteTextView**. Its working fine.

But when i enter some keyword(some text in the AutoCompleteTextView) it was giving the places according to the **Current Location**. but i need the places from the **United States**

Using the following Url to get the places

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=?&types=geocode&sensor=false&AIzaSyAIjrt28Os8Eyp0rVQbdkKNXNi5YrGx0AE

**Example**

- "New" text entered
- Giving the places near to my CurrentLocation..(Places near current location)
- Expected Places from the UnitedStates.. (NewYork, NewBerlin, NewLenox)

Please can i get any luck

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to [this article](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/query?hl=de) you can pass a *location* and a *radius* as parameter to your query which should be a solution to your problem.
As location you could pass the middle of the United States and a radius that fits to all borders.

Taking [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516622/google-places-api-how-to-get-regions-of-a-country) into consideration this seems to be impossible other than the way I described it.

Comment: Please check the Updated Question to get the used url to get the Places

Comment: Thanks the article helps alot!