# Country State select list using google api

Tags: javascript

I have a list of countries generating dynamically from my database. On change event for the select list, when I select a country, I want to generate another select list for selecting states.

I am trying to achieve this using Google Maps API.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this. Struggling from 5 hours on this.

Thanks 
Phaniraj N

Comment: What have you tried? In what is this related to the Google Maps API? How are the countries and states stored in your database? What language do you use?

Comment: Please specify how is the list of countries being generated dynamically. What is the data source. I believe what you are trying to achieve may require access to google maps data tables

Answer (score -2):

I just tried a quick googled around and found that google seems like don't provide such service.

But you may use other services like:
http://www.dyngeometry.com/web/WorldRegion.aspx

Another finding:
[Google places API - How to get regions of a country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516622/google-places-api-how-to-get-regions-of-a-country)

hope it helps

Comment: *I have a list of countries generating dynamically from my database.* OP is not asking for a way to retrieve a list of countries/states but how to generate a select list of states when selecting a country.